# Add a counting condition into dense_rank window Function SQL

Tags: sql, dense-rank

I have a function that counts how many times you've visited and if you have converted or not.
What I'd like is for the dense_rank to re-start the count, if there has been a conversion:

```
SELECT
          uid,
          channel,
          time,
          conversion,
          dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY time asc) as visit_order
FROM table
```

current table output:
this customer (`uid`) had a conversion at visit 18 and now I would want  the `visit_order` count from `dense_rank` to restart at 0 for the same customer until it hits the next conversion that is non-null.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this (I do not like "try this" ):

```
SELECT
   id,
   ts,
   conversion,
   -- SC,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id,SC) R
FROM (
   SELECT
      id,
      ts,
      conversion,
      -- COUNT(conversion) OVER (PARTITION BY id, conversion=0 ORDER BY ts ) CC,
      SUM(CASE WHEN conversion=1 THEN 1000 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts ) - SUM(CASE WHEN conversion=1 THEN 1000 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts )%1000 SC
   FROM sample
   ORDER BY ts
   ) x
ORDER BY ts;
```

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=673b59dcb865c06111a9e0d5d889915a)

output:

| id | ts | conversion | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-15 10:00:00 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-16 10:00:00 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-17 10:00:00 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-01-18 10:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-19 10:00:00 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-20 10:00:00 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-01-21 10:00:00 | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 2022-01-22 10:00:00 | 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 10:00:00 | 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 2022-01-24 10:00:00 | 0 | 7 |
| 1 | 2022-01-25 10:00:00 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-26 10:00:00 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-27 10:00:00 | 0 | 3 |

Comment: Thanks, Luuk! Very elegant solution and worked like a charm!

Comment: follow-up question: If I needed to have the counter restart only after the conversion, any hints? I've tried using a lag() but not succeeded with it.

Comment: There's more than one conversion in my answer, So I do not understand why you would only start counting after conversion.  But in the DBFIDDLE is a commented column named `SC` did you see the value of it? It's `0` when no conversion is done.

Comment: yes indeed there are multiple conversions per customer ID, the idea is that we count how many times the user came to the page until he converted. So re-starting the counter after he has converted, not on the conversion event itself.

Comment: Ah, you do mean that the line with conversion=1 should have a count equal to 0?   In that case you can just subtract 1 from the column `R`.

Comment: actually the opposite :D I need the line with conversion equal to 4 or 8 in the above example, but then R +1 would work, no?

Comment: No, that will not work because counting does start on the line with conversion=1.  It should start one line later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244231/discussion-between-ykjk-and-luuk).